# What is the address of the servers that run the BlobVault and authd API?

Tags: ripple

I am building a native Ripple Android wallet.

I understand that the BlobVault is currently centralized so what are the Ripple Labs server addresses that is safe to connect to those API servers - BlobVault and authd?

Maybe my understanding is limited and I am asking the wrong question, but:

`What is the address of the servers that run the BlobVault and authd API?`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The correct domain addresses for Ripple Labs are listed at `https://ripple.com/ripple.txt`.

See `https://wiki.ripple.com/Ripple.txt`